# preventing a window from deminiaturizing from dock

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

How to prevent a window to deminiaturizing when a user click on the dock tile of the window?
In one part of my application , I am miniaturizing the window and then have to ensure that user cannot deminiaturize it for a specified time .The application has more than one window.

Please suggest how to do this in cocoa.

Comment: So, did we answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines (see section ['Minimizing and Expanding Windows'](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TP9)) and as a result there is almost certainly no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. That is something the OS is doing and you can't influence it. You need to adapt your design so it's no problem if the user unhides the window.